# Managing MS Excel's Worksheet protection properties using java

Tags: apache-poi, jxl, java

I need to prevent editing, copying and selecting cells in worksheet, but there should be a possibility to change width and height of rows and columns. I can do this using Excel Application by choosing different protection options but i cannot find anything like this in java libraries.
I mean I can set password to make document read-only but user still can copy information and change it. I need a tool which will allow to change protection properties of worksheet programmatically.

Is there anything like this in such libraries as apache poi or jxl? if not is there any library which can do it (much better if it will be free-to-use)?

Thanks for your replies and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

to make your excel-sheet protected do this:
sheet.getSettings().setProtected(true);

and to password-protect your sheets-individually do this:
sheet.getSettings().setPassword("password");

but...i've seen that password doesnt work..

Comment: Main problem is not to protect sheet with password (i can do this) but to set very specific protection properties. You can see what i mean by trying manually protect sheet with password in excel. Go to 'Review -> Protect Sheet'. You will see dialog with textbox for typing password and some checkboxes below. What i need is to check or uncheck this checkboxes in my program. How can i do this?